# Memory leak/infinite loop issue with multiplayer game: React State and Firestore snapshot listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am trying to write a simple multiplayer game involving a board of tiles. I need real time updates so that all players see all tile updates when they happen. This is my first time using Firestore or building a game with real time updates. I am using React with React Hooks to build my game.

```
const [tiles, setTiles] = useState([]);
```

Tiles is an array of 25 objects. The logic for starting a new game and initial setting of new batch of tiles is elsewhere, and I don't think relevant for the problem.

On Firestore, I have a `games` collection. Each games document includes the `tiles` array.

When first loaded, we use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array to subscribe to the onSnapshot listener for the game, and update our local state when snapshots are received.
I used the example from the documentation to attempt to only update the local state when the updates are from the server: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0#events-local-changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    return db
            .collection('games')
            .doc(code)
            .onSnapshot((doc) => {
                var source = doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites ? 'Local' : 'Server';
                if (source !== 'Local') {
                    console.log('Game snapshot!');
                    // get the tiles from the database and update local state to reflect
                    setTiles(doc.data().tiles);
                }
            })
    }, []
)
```

When turns happen, tiles are clicked and then new state of the tiles is set after the click:

```
const onTileClick = (tile, index) => {
    // ...
    // perform some logic, calculate value of new_tiles
    // ...

    // Then update tiles in local state
    setTiles(new_tiles);
}
```

And whenever the tiles change, we again use `useEffect()` to monitor for tile changes and update the Firestore game.

```
useEffect(() => {
    return db
        .collection('games')
        .doc(code)
        // send the new tiles to the server
        .update({tiles: tiles})
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('Tiles updated!');
        })
        .catch((res) => {
            console.log('Error updating tiles!', res);
        });
}, [tiles]);
```

The problem, as you can probably see, is that whenever I click a tile, it starts an infinite loop of setting tiles, triggering a snapshot, setting the tiles again.. etc...

This is only happening when I have two browser windows open (one in incognito mode to mimic two players), I think what's happening is, when the tiles are set from one player's window, it triggers the snapshot for the other player, which sets their tiles, which triggers a snapshot for the other player, setting their tiles ...etc...

Clearly I am not using React Hooks in the best way here. Does anyone have any better suggestions of how to manage React state with a Firestore snapshot? Or do I just need to be more granular in the onSnapshot listener to check for actual differences before updating React state? The problem is, there are going to be multiple fields once I've got a bit further, not just 'tiles'... so more differences to check for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the `setTiles()` on a player cause it to write back to the database? I don't think that's supposed to happen, is it? I'd usually only expect some user actions (clicking on tiles/objects) to write to the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What do you mean by 'on a player' exactly? When the tile is clicked (`onTileClick`), or when the game first loads from the database (the `useEffect()` call with empty dependency) the state of the tiles is updated, which is why `setTiles()` is called. The `useEffect` listener on tile changes causes it to write back to the database because we update the game to notify the other players a tile has been changed. But yes, there is a hole in my logic somewhere, I'm just struggling to know what to change exactly to fix the loop but still keep the code clean.

Comment: But calling `setTiles()` shouldn't trigger a write back to the database, does it? Maybe I'm missing something: can you show the write operation that causes the loop in your question too?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Well, it depends. If a tile has been clicked, yes, it should, to let the other players know. But I see your point, I think I need to be more specific about when I write back to the database, and probably remove that `useEffect()` call on any tile changes (the 3rd code block above).

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the `.update({tiles: tiles})` in that third block. Writing to the database in a `useEffect` when you're listening to the same data in another `useEffect` sounds like a potential problem indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider implementing some way to determine if `setTiles` should actually be called in your snapshot callback.  Right now you are checking `doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites`, which doesn't tell you for certain if something actually changed.  It just tells you if the server sent you an update.  Consider writing some logic to compare the current and prior contents of the document to see if something actually changed that needs rendering, and only call `setTiles` if that's the case.  That might stop the ping-ponging of data between the users.